# A way to analyze and compute a huge Oracle data on daily basis

Tags: java, spring-batch, etl

I need to calculate the summary data from various transaction tables in the primary Oracle database of our core engine. I have planned write this as a multi-threaded Java program which will be scheduled as a job that runs every midnight; the program will extract the data from various transaction log tables joining other tables with it from the database, calculate and store back the result to a separate table. The log tables usually will contain millions of data with some tables partitioned daily and some on monthly.

The GUI (the dashboard) platform would request these information through a separate webservice that already exists in providing various other details. Almost all the modules in the project uses Spring framework, so I thought to use the Spring-Batch with the scheduling capability. As I started some research before starting the design on this, I found various other techniques used such as the ETL tools, scheduling in the database itself, real-time data analysis and other similar techniques.

Am I over approaching the problem in my hand? Did my earlier approach a right one? Or is there a way, a framework on Java, to do this process in real-time, say while the data is processed (while the core engine is processing the data), such that there is no need to write a separate job to do this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) which is a Engine to process high volume data.

Spring XD offers a lot readers (jdbc, file, jms), processors and writers (jdbc, file, jms) out of box and you can write your own readers, writers, processors easily.

Spring XD uses the Unix style source, pipe, sink to connect multiple processors. You can see this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2015/04/simple-twitter-sentiment-notification.html) for a small example of the application of Spring XD with High volume twitter data.